# Branch of complex logarithm in a region containing $0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Question:
>
> 1. Define a branch $f(z)$ of $\log\left( \frac{z-i}{z-1} \right)$ on a region containing $0$.
> 2. Find the radius of convergence of the power series expansion of $f(z)$ centered at $z=0$.

**My attempt:** I have considered the region to be any disc centered at $0$ of radius $r >0$ so that $D(0, r) \subset D(0,1)$ and using the principal branch of Log $z$. However, it seems that even for sufficiently small $r>0$, there exists $z_0 \in D(0, r)$ so that $\frac{z_0 - i}{z_0 - 1} \in (-\infty, 0]$. Also, if I would to choose the branch of Log $z$ defined on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{yi \colon y \geq 0\}$, there exists $z_0 \in D(0,r)$ so that $\frac{z_0 - i}{z_0 - 1} \in \{yi \colon y \geq 0\}$. May I know if there any gaps in my understanding the complex logarithm and its branch cuts?

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $D$ is any disk around $0$ such that $x+y <1$ for all $x+iy \in D$ ($x,y \in \mathbb R$) then $\frac {z-i}{z-1}$ does not lie on the negative imaginary axis, so there is an analytic branch of logarithm in $D$.

Answer for 2) is $\frac  1 2$.

Comment: thank you, I overlooked the branch cut for the negative imaginary axis.